# Visual Studio 2022 gives error "'Site' must not be null in order to access a required service." when trying to add menu item

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I've got a `contextMenuStrip` and often (not always, but I haven't noticed a repeatable pattern yet) I get the error dialog:

> 'Site' must not be null in order to access a required service.

when trying to type in the "Type Here" field. It happens the second I click the cursor into the field.

[image]

Anyone have any idea what's causing this?

Comment: Seems like a rather random error... googling around I found a troubleshooting page here: https://github.com/dotnet/winforms/blob/main/docs/designer/troubleshooting.md I also found a different site say cleaning out their bin and obj folder helped.

Answer (score 1):

This made the problem go away for me. I do not know which step did it, but it seems to be working normally now.

First, all the designer does is write the `[FormName].Designer.cs` page for you. You can always put the entries in for the subitems in yourself and VS seems to be fine with that. I started this, looking at an older project that had menu subitems (and worked perfectly in VS22) as a model.

1. In the object definitions at the bottom of your Designer file, add the declaration for the menu item(s).
2. In the hidden section, in the instantiations, add a line(s) to create your menu item(s).
3. It was at this point I noticed the older, working project all the instantiations were prefixed with `this` (i.e. `this.LogFileToolStripMenuItem=new ToolStripMenuItem`) and on a second menu item that needed submenu items I added the `this` and went back into the designer and everything worked normally (and continued to do so, no error message) from there on out. I don't know which part of this fixed it but when I went back into the designer file to see what happened if I removed the `this` the designer editor had already stripped the `this` out, but everything still worked.
4. You need to set the three properties for a tool strip Menu Item. You can probably copy one of the existing ones and just change things to fit your new `toolstripmenuitem`.
5. The last thing you need to do is add the submenus to the parent. In the property definition section for the parent, add an `AddRange` line:

`cmsLogging.DropDownItems.AddRange(new ToolStripItem[] { cmsLogging_LogFile, cmsLogging_ShowLogFile, cmsLogging_ShowLogFileDirectory });`

After this and restarting the form designer the menu items were present and everything looked normal. As a bonus the error message is gone away. It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks George. I'm not sure just manually adding objects (code) to the designer is the solution. I normally do that all the time anyway. Mine seems to happen randomly, usually after just stopping a debug session and the designer window shows. Then when I click any context menu that'll happen. I usually "fix" it by either doing a "rebuild solution", or just close the designer window and reopen it. But it happens often enough to be a pretty big annoyance.

Comment: It might be worth clarifying what actually causes this error or why this helps if you know.